# Changing a nvarchar column into a Date format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column called `DT_APP` which contains dates in two formats

1. `Sep  4 2012  6:19PM`
2. `2013-04-30 23:38.34`

I need to convert 1) into 2) in the column but I need it to be in `nvarchar(19)` as the data type is in `nvarchar(19)`.

I appreciate it should be in `Datetime` format but Its been set to `nvarchar(19)`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

So, assuming that those are the only two formats of your column, then you can do the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),CONVERT(DATETIME,DT_APP,100),120)
FROM YourTable
WHERE DT_APP LIKE '%[aA-zZ]%'
```

**UPDATED**

Ok, if you want another column, then you can first create it and then fill the values:

```
-- First create a new column
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD DT_APP2 DATETIME;

-- Fill that column with DATETIME values
UPDATE YourTable
SET DT_APP2 =   CASE WHEN DT_APP LIKE '%[aA-zZ]%'
                THEN CONVERT(DATETIME,DT_APP,100)
                ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME,DT_APP,120) END
```

After that, you can check the column to see if the values are correct and only then you should delete the `DT_APP` column.

**UPDATE 2**
If you just need to update current values, then just do:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET DT_APP = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19),CONVERT(DATETIME,DT_APP,100),120)
WHERE DT_APP LIKE '%[aA-zZ]%'
```

Comment: Thank You Lamak but I need to convert the actual Column into yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS so I have one unified column format instead of two. Thanks.

Comment: I need it in the same column. I need it in Nvarchar(19). Thanks.

Comment: @KaisMalique Look, you said that your column was `NVARCHAR(19)` already, so you just need to do the `UPDATE`. I updated my answer again

Comment: This is what I got. Error Message: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @KaisMalique Then you probably have bad data there and not just the formats you said. Can't really help you with that

Comment: @KaisMalique Then post some of the data on an sqlfiddle to test it

Comment: @KaisMalique You should *really* check your data or ask a new question about whatever your new issue is.

Comment: @KaisMalique Sure, you don't know how to format the dates but you are sure the Data is fine.

Comment: @Blam I know the data is fine not sure what your implying!!! If you can't help please refrain from making unhelpful comments.

Comment: @KaisMalique: So far you've got a couple of *sensible* suggestions. If they fail for you, how can we help without seeing the data? Blam's point was that you should not expect us to just *believe* what you said about your data being fine. I can also say: these suggestions are fine (and I mean it!). However, you *can* test them and see that they fail against your data and we *can't* do the same. So please give us something to work with rather than making unhelpful statements. (`The Data is fine` is *not* helpful in this case.)